# How to calculate an exe file creation time from its shortcut file

Tags: windows

Is there any way to find out the creation time of an executable file by analyzing its shortcut file? . I just want to know the manual method not built in functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The Shortcut does not contain this information - the properties of the Target need to be inspected. See [MS-SHLLINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx). (So it's a two-step process, as per above.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Shell Link Binary File Format MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx).

One of the members of the [ShellLinkHeader structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd891343.aspx) is `CreationTime`, but it may or may not be accurate. You should look up the target and analyze it directly.

If you do want to use the shortcut's `CreationTime` value, [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188768) describes how to convert a `FILETIME` structure to a readable string.

Comment: Hi,

   Thanks Kevin.. Those links were very helpful. But I still have a doubt.
In the sample structure they provided (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871375.aspx),
the created time is at offset 1C and its 8 bytes long. 
The value I could read from this is D0 E9 EE F2 15 15 C9 01. How can I convert this value to actual date ? (ie. 9/12/08, 8:27:17PM)

Comment: It's a `FILETIME` structure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230324.aspx). You would use the value in a function like `FileTimeToSystemTime`.

Comment: Thanks. But there is no information regarding how this function(FileTimeToSystemTime)works. I want to know the steps involving the conversion of  D0 E9 EE F2 15 15 C9 01 to 9/12/08, 8:27:17PM ..If you have any idea, please share

Comment: This article describes, among other things, exactly how to convert a `FILETIME` structure into a readable string: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188768

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect what we've discussed in the comments. It *is* possible (but not recommended) to get a creation time from a shortcut.